# Implementing JavaScript code to ReactJs logic doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am new to react and i need some help.

I am trying to implement some hamburger menu icon that someone put on codepen:

```
https://codepen.io/rss/pen/OJxZrR
```

The problem is that i can't get animation to work.

```
import "../../index.css";

const [style, setStyle] = useState("nav-container");


const changeStyle = () => {
setStyle("pushed")};
```

I tried something like this and I added button onClick for changing state but it doesn't work

```
       <button
          onClick={() => {
            changeStyle();
          }}
        >
          <div id="nav-container">
            <div className="toggle-icon">
              <span className="bar"></span>
              <span className="bar"></span>
              <span className="bar"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </button>
```

Comment: In what way does this code "not work"?  All it does is set a state value which is then never used.  What are you expecting the code to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the state as a toggle and set the class pushed if the state is true

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [pushed, setPushed] = useState(false);

  const changeStyle = () => {
    setPushed(!pushed);
  };
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        changeStyle();
      }}
    >
      <div id="nav-container">
        <div className={`toggle-icon ${pushed ? "pushed" : ""}`}>
          <span className="bar"></span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide dynamic id to the div, as :

```
<div id={style}>
            <div className="toggle-icon">
              <span className="bar"></span>
              <span className="bar"></span>
              <span className="bar"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to toggle `pushed` class on `nav-container` div

Change your onClick handler to this

```js
const changeStyle = () => {
  const navContainer = document.getElementById("nav-container");
  navContainer.classList.toggle("pushed");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Some precautions -

- Make sure your button hover make the cursor pointer. Otherwise can    have low z-index problem
- const changeStyle = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setPushed(!pushed);
  };
- There is no content inside it. So make sure it's existence.